# Programmatically combine pdf files with Adobe Acrobar

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I have a scenario where we have to combine multiple PDF a file into one PDF file. We are using Adobe Acrobat to work with PDF like converting DOC/PPT/XLS file to PDF and Add watermark in PDF. 
Adobe Acrobat DC have an option to combine file in a single pdf file but I need the solution automate. 
Any suggestion or code snippet would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Exactly *how* automated do you need it to be? Acrobat isn't licensed to be used as a black box so even though it can be automated to a degree, there tends to be some level of user interaction to get everything going.

Comment: We are using on a server with the license to make the process automated and we are able to create the PDF and add the Watermark, but stuck to combine the PDF they have not provided anything in SDK. Regarding exactly how automated - 1. We need any method that takes two PDF file path and combines them together or 2. Even adding a page from another PDF would also work.

Comment: Ok - Stop. You really *don't* want to use Acrobat in that kind of environment. Acrobat is a desktop application, it wasn't engineered or tested to be operated as a server tool. People have been trying to do exactly that for decades and it's never ended well for them. There are PDF libraries and web services from Adobe and others that are *engineered* for server use. I *strongly* suggest you familiarize yourself with a few of those and decide which will best suit your needs.